# Chrome randomly fires touch events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, touch

I have a 21.5 inch multitouch screen. It works fine with pretty much everything, and I use it all the time.

However, when making a slideshow with [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js), which supports multitouch, in Chrome 22.0.1221.0, the slide skips randomly after a swipe. I've tried almost everything to make it go away - but to no avail.

Is this a reveal.js bug? I've tried using Phantom Limb, and the skipping doesn't occur with it, so this *may* be a Chrome bug, but I can find no documentation of it.

How can I prevent this from happening?